# getting error code while connecting to sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am getting an error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.]

during connecting to sql server 2012  from my visual studio for c#. when debugged pointing the error is at :

```
connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: check connectionString in web.config or app.config

Comment: Can you post some more code around this line?

Comment: probably you don't have "MyConnection" defined in your configuration file. It has to be under <connectionstrings>

Comment: I 2nd the comments about not having "MyConnection" defined. I had exactly the same error and couldn't figure out why it said NullReferenceException. This is difficult to debug when your code is outside of any function and loads on form load. Make sure you have the connection string set in your app.config and you will be fine :)